# Implementing sign in with twitter using Twitter4J library

Tags: jsf, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I have a web application using JSF.

on my page I have a button that invokes `doTwitterLogin()`

```
public void doTwitterLogin() {
    try {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        String url = req.getRequestURL().toString();
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer("xxx", "xxx");
        RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(url);

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("requestToken_token", requestToken.getToken());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("requestToken_secret", requestToken.getTokenSecret());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

i get an exception after debugging in `RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(url);` part.

```
SEVERE: 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <error>Desktop applications only support the oauth_callback value 'oob'</error>
  <request>/oauth/request_token</request>
</hash>
```

reference: http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

You have marked your application as a 'desktop application'. You shall change that to web application using application settings.